# Retry Cloud Functions for Firebase until it succeeds

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to create a cloud function which sends an e-mail based on a change in my database. I use postmark, but that's not relevant for this function. I looked at the [firebase-examples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/email-confirmation/functions/index.js).

My question is: What if the mail service returns an error or if the mail service is temporary down? I don't see any form of error handling in the examples.

My 'solution' would be to try again in 5 minutes for example. Is that possible and advisable in cloud functions?

Answer (score 2):

If you throw an exception when sending the email fails, it should retry the function up to 7 days.

Open detailed usage states for your function in the firebase console

[image]

Edit the function

[image]

Click the link to configure retry

[image]

Enable "Retry on failure"

[image]

I haven't tried it myself yet for your use case, but it works for my storage triggered function when it fails.

Comment: Thank you for this suggested solution. I just did the steps above, will follow up if it helps over the next couple of days.

Comment: This is not available anymore, since GCP updated web UI and changing "Retry on Failure" requires function re-deployment, which will fail. https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/162440541